# Get secure store service passphrase

Tags: 2010, secure-store

I am quite new to SharePoint. We are setting up a clone of production (SP 2010). However, we do not have the **passphrase** of Secure Store service.
Kindly let know how we can retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer to this is wrong, the command posted resets the farm pass phrase, not the pass phrase for the secure store master key. These are separate and different. What you want to do to reset the secure store pass phrase is this:

```
$newPassPhrase = "abcDEF123!"
$proxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ?{$_.TypeName -eq 'Secure Store Service Application Proxy'}
Update-SPSecureStoreMasterKey -ServiceApplicationProxy $proxy -Passphrase $newPassPhrase
```

see more here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/update-spsecurestoremasterkey?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, Sharepoint doesn't store the passphrase, the only option is to reset it again via Powershell as the following.

```
$passphrase = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "your new passphrase" -asPlainText -Force
Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase -Confirm
```